# What material is this pipe? Options for new 2" Union

Tags: plumbing, pvc, cpvc

[image]

I'd like to go 2 inch pvc into my new pool pump from that valve. What are my options? This pipe is 1.5 inches, not metal, but I'm not 100% that is CPVC either, but I'm not an expert. I have a 2" union on my new pump that I need to connect to somehow.

[image]

Comment: I would expect CPVC or PVC. There are no markings on the pipe?

Comment: None that I can see.

Comment: It looks like grey PVC pipe to me.  Might be Schedule 80 (which is usually grey) vs. Schedule 40 which is usually white.

Comment: Added a picture I had of better focus when the pot was still on.

Comment: What's the problem, exactly? You're not using solvent welding, are you? It shouldn't really matter, then.

Comment: @isherwood Yes, should've mentioned that. I need to get a 2 inch union on, I was planning on gluing. I don't have room here without cutting or removing this nipple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of small pre-threaded nipples like that are only offered in gray Schedule 80, because that way they can be used for water OR electrical purposes and the resellers don't have to carry inventory of both types. White Schedule 40 cannot be used for electrical conduit.

Comment: I can't be sure this is the answer, but it makes more sense than CPVC, and gives a logical reason for having this one section of 80. I got primer and glue that works on 40, 80, and cpvc, so I'm covered whatever it is.